# Extremely slow processing by Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have the following entity

```
  @Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Validated
public class Location {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
protected Long id;

    String province;

    String city;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "location", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<FeaturedStoreRank> featuredStoreRanks;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "location", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<FeaturedDeliveryRank> featuredDeliveryRanks;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "location", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<FeaturedDealRank> featuredDealRanks;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "location", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AllStoreRank> allStoreRanks;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "location", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AllDeliveryRank> allDeliveryRanks;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "location", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<RecommendedRank> recommendedRanks;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "location", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AllDealRank> allDealRanks;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryCity", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> primaryUsers;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "secondaryCity", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> secondaryUsers;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "locations", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Store> stores;
}
```

The call https://server:8080/api/v1/locations takes more 2 seconds of processing time before TTFB (before server starts sending results)

I've tried marking all of those associations with LAZY, still slow.

I've tried using Spring Data Rest projection, to limit the number of fields coming back. Still same slow speed.

I've tried writing a native SQL query like this:

```
@Query(
            value = "SELECT * from location\n",
            nativeQuery = true)
    public Collection<Location> test();
```

Still slow.

I've tried running the SQL query directly agains the database, it takes 0.2 seconds to return all the records.

So clearly spring somehow it taking 2 seconds to process the data from db, but why? How do I fix this?

Comment: Inspect the logs to see what SQL statements get executed, and where the time is spent. If that doesn't yield sufficient information, use a profiler

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you execute against your database is the one that *only loads* the raw `Location` instances from the database *without* any of the related entities. Spring Data REST will then hand this entity over to Jackson which wants to render the properties and this will cause *additional* queries to be executed for each property. Depending on what these classes look like, the rendering of those will trigger additional queries and so on.

Make sure you understand that Spring Data REST operates on the notion of aggregates, i.e. well defined clusters of entities that business rules are applied on. Spring Data REST is *not* a tool to easily dump your database tables into HTTP resources without thinking.

Comment: But what's exactly what I suspected and I tried to avoid that situation by asking SDR to render only fields that does not require queries (in this case province and city) by using a projection. How can I confirm that SDR is not triggering queries and how to I avoid this?